# 'Read' command stripping '\n' string

Tags: bash

I want to extract data from a file which looks like this :

```
BK20120802130531:/home/michael/Scripts/usb_backup.sh
BK20120802130531:/home/michael/Scripts/yad_0.17.1.1-1_i386.deb
BK20120802130731:/home/michael/Scripts/gbk.sh
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/alt-notify-send.sh
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/bk.bak
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/bk.sh
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/demande_password.sh
```

The idea is to show on the screen (without creating a temporary file, nor modifying the original file) what follows :

```
alt-notify-send.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
bk.bak
/home/michael/Scripts
bk.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
demande_password.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
gbk.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
usb_backup.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
yad_0.17.1.1-1_i386.deb
/home/michael/Scripts
```

To sum up :

1. Strip the characters before ':'
2. Put the filenames before their corresponding directory
3. Sort the filenames by alphabetical order
4. Do a carriage return between each filename and its corresponding directory

I succeed doing all this, but there is still an ugly thing in my code concerning point #4 :

```
cut -f 2 -d ':' $big_file | \
sort -u | \
while read file ; do
   echo "$(basename "$file")zipzapzupzop$(dirname "$file")" # <-- ugly thing #1
done | \
sort -dfb | \
while read line ; do
   echo $line
done | \
sed 's/zipzapzupzop/\n/' # <-- ugly thing #2
```

At the beginning, I had written :

```
echo "$(basename "$file")\n$(dirname "$file")"
```

in place of ugly thing#1, in order to be able to do

```
echo -e "$line"
```

in the second while boucle. However, the read command strips each time the '\n' string, so that I obtain

```
alt-notify-send.shn/home/michael/Scripts
bk.bakn/home/michael/Scripts
bk.shn/home/michael/Scripts
demande_password.shn/home/michael/Scripts
gbk.shn/home/michael/Scripts
usb_backup.shn/home/michael/Scripts
yad_0.17.1.1-1_i386.debn/home/michael/Scripts
```

I tried to protect the '\' character by another '\', but the result is the same.

```
man read
```

is of no help either. So, is it a proper way to do this ?

Comment: `echo "$(basename "$file")` doesn't quote `$file`, the second double quote ends the quoting. You need to escape the internal quotes or use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is a shell builtin, and `man read` may be giving you the docs for the (mostly unrelated) syscall.

`read -r` will prevent `read` from processing `\` sequences.

The whole thing could have been done with a single `awk` script though:

```
awk '
    {
        start = index($0, ":") + 1
        end = match($0, "[^/]*$")
        out[NR] = substr($0, end) "\n" substr($0, start, end - start - 1)
    }
    END {
        asort(out)
        for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++)
            print out[i]
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following pipeline (should be on one line, I've split it and added comments for readability):

```
| sed -e 's/^[^:]*://'             # Remove from start of line to first ':'
      -e 's?/\([^/]*$\)? \1?'      # Replace final '/' with a space
| sort -k2                         # Sort on column 2 (filename)
| awk '{print $2"\n"$1}'           # Reverse fields
```

See the following transcript:

```
echo 'BK20120802130531:/home/michael/Scripts/usb_backup.sh
BK20120802130531:/home/michael/Scripts/yad_0.17.1.1-1_i386.deb
BK20120802130731:/home/michael/Scripts/gbk.sh
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/alt-notify-send.sh
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/bk.bak
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/bk.sh
BK20120802130131:/home/michael/Scripts/demande_password.sh'
    | sed -e 's/^[^:]*://'
          -e 's?/\([^/]*$\)? \1?'
    | sort -k2
    | awk '{print $2"\n"$1}'

alt-notify-send.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
bk.bak
/home/michael/Scripts
bk.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
demande_password.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
gbk.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
usb_backup.sh
/home/michael/Scripts
yad_0.17.1.1-1_i386.deb
/home/michael/Scripts
```

Just keep in mind that sort may not work as expected with lines containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to handle spaces in filenames, you can do this:

```
cat $bigfile | sed 's/.*://' | while read file; do
  echo "$(basename $file) $(dirname $file)"
done | sort | awk '{print $1"\n"$2}'
```

Comment: Useless use of cat. `sed 's/.*//' $bigfile`, or `< $bigfile sed 's/.*://'`

Comment: @chepner: I think it makes the pipeline cleaner, but others may disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have hash tags in your filenames you could use this `coreutils` pipeline:

```
cut -d: -f2- infile               \
| sed -r 's,(.*)/([^/]*)$,\2#\1,' \
| sort -t'#'                      \
| tr '#' '\n'
```

- `cut` removes the first part.
- `sed` splits the path, swaps filename and directory and delimits them with a `#`.
- `sort` hash tag delimited text.
- `tr` finally replaces the hash tag with a newline.

If you know the number of path elements, you can use the simpler version:

```
cut -d: -f2- infile \
| sort -t/ -k4,4    \
| sed 's,(.*)/([^/]*)$,\2\n\1,'
```